# Remove a shipping method from a store view

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, phtml

I have a magento store with 1 website operating 2 store views within it.
I want to hide a shipping method which is displayed in a list item in one of the store views.

I understand I can use css display:none for the li, but I am not sure how piece everything together. From my research I have the following ideas...

The css part

```
display:none
```

the phtml part (not sure which file I put this in)

```
if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == YOUR STORE VIEW ID HERE){//do stuff}//orif (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == YOUR STORE VIEW CODE HERE){//do stuff}
```

a bit of code to include a file somewhere to load the css based on the correct store id

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><file>css/additional.css</file></action>
        </reference>
```

This is all I have gathered from researching various posts, just not sure how to piece it all together.
I keep reading terminology like "blocks" and "controllers", but have no idea what these actually refer to. Although I know they belong somewhere in app/code, just require specific paths and area in file to insert code.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the phtml file location can be different depending on which template / modules  you are using.
eg if you are using onepage checkout module it might be in design/frontend/...Your theme/package../ template/checkout/onepage.phtml

However you can turn on template path hints for the particular store view ..
In `System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Template Path hints -> Yes` ..
[Select the particular store on top left]
Clear cache and visit checkout page you will get the file paths ..

You can also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348237/disable-shipping-in-magento-to-a-specific-country-in-all-stores-except-one

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read this article. 
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/17/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-shipping-method-step/